# How to get the most recurring row from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to get the most recurring amount, along side the it description from the below dataframe. The length of the dataframe is longer that what I displayed here.

**dataframe**

```
          description                        amount type    cosine_group
1       295302|service fee 295302|microloa  1500.0   D         24
2       1292092|rpmt microloan|71302        20000.0  D         31
3       qr q10065116702 fund trf 0002080661 30000.0  D         12
4       qr q10060597280 fund trf 0002080661 30000.0  D         12
5       1246175|service fee 1246175|microlo 3000.0   D         24
6       qr q10034118487 fund trf 0002080661 2000.0   D         12
```

Here I tried using the grouby function

`df.groupby(['cosine_group'])['amount'].value_counts()[:2]`

the above code returns

```
cosine_group  amount 
12            30000.0    7
              30000.0    6
```

I need the `description` along side the most `recurring amount`

**Expected output is :**

```
     description                                amount
   qr q10065116702 fund trf 0002080661         30000.0  
   qr q10060597280 fund trf 0002080661         30000.0
```

Comment: "I would like to get the most recurring amount". THen Why did you used groupby?

Comment: Because I thought I can use `groupby` to  get the group that occur most and from there extract the  **amount** & **description**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mode:

```
  description  amount type
0           A           15
1           B         2000
2           C         3000
3           C         3000
4           C         3000
5           D           30
6           E           20
7           A           15

df[df['amount type'].eq(df['amount type'].mode().loc[0])]

  description  amount type
2           C         3000
3           C         3000
4           C         3000
```

Explaination:

```
df[mask] # will slice the dataframe based on boolean series (select the True rows) which is called a mask
df['amount type'].eq(3000) # .eq() stands for equal, it is a synonym for == in pandas
df['amount type'].mode() # is the mode of multiple values, which is defined as the most common
df['amount type'].loc[0] # returns the result with index 0, to get int instead of series
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, but I think I need more clarification on what is happening in the above expression.

What is the  function of the `eq` function in the above expression

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie  Updated my answer and added an explaiantion

Comment: how do ensure that I always get top 3 most occurring amount?

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie, this is a slightly different question. Could you create another question, and write the link to it here? Because this way future readers have it easier to find the correct solution to their problem.